# GH Pages CSS file missing or SCSS not processed

Tags: sass, github-pages

I've copied most of my site so far from [this example](https://github.com/mdo/jekyll-example), the biggest exception being that I'm working in a `/docs` directory instead of in the root.

In my default.html layout, I have:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/style.css?v=" | append: site.github.build_revision }}" />
```

which spits out the expected html element pointing to the css file:

```
https://example.com/css/style.css?v=2ddde426cabbbb39ded17b9a8c95c31f14416e35
```

Which gives me a 404.

I've seen other posts where the problem is fixed with adding /assets/ to the url - when I go to [/assets/css/style.css](https://thatrootbeerblog.com/assets/css/style.css?v=2ddde426cabbbb39ded17b9a8c95c31f14416e35) I get a wall of text and I'm not sure where it came from. I have 2 styles in my base.scss file currently, and neither of them are in this file.

/docs/css/style.scss:

```
---
# Front matter comment to ensure Jekyll properly reads file.
---

// Imports
@import "base";
```

/docs/_sass/base.scss:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700');
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  background:#444;
  font-family:Roboto, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight:300;
}
```

/docs/_config.yml:

```
url: https://thatrootbeerblog.com
sass:
  sass_dir:         _sass
  style:            :compressed
```

I am not getting any compilation errors reported in github, but I've been unable to get my local to work (not done much with ruby locally).

Am I missing something obvious with the SCSS->CSS compilation or directory structure?

**Other attempts**

I tried moving the style.scss file to /docs/assets/css/style.scss per [this page about customizing jekyll theme pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme), but still no change or error. /assets/css/style.css still shows a wall of css that does not include my own and I cannot otherwise locate.

**Also tried**

Selected a theme (I did not have one specified in my _config.yaml) and the /assets/css/style.css file updates. It still does not have my style.scss file in it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the "leap-day"-theme "jekyll-theme-leap-day", and had the same problem at first.

After I read the README of the [The Leap day theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/leap-day#stylesheet) and compared it to [Adding a theme to your GitHub Pages site using Jekyll - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll#customizing-your-themes-css)

I changed the `@import` to the given value there, and it worked.

```
@import "";
```

was the value suggested by the GitHub docs,

but for the lead-day theme it really was

```
@import "{{ site.theme }}";
```

So my tip, read the docs of your theme too... Shame on me...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the "final answer" but it seems that the erroneous CSS is because a jekyll theme is used by default whether it's set in the config or not.

I ended up setting a theme, then recreating my own files in the same structure to overwrite the base theme files.

/docs/_config.yml added:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-slate
```

Then add my own file at /docs/_scss/jekyll-theme-slate.scss, which renders out new CSS now at /assets/css/style.css.

Ideally you'd be able to define your own files without overriding this unseen directory structure, but it at least works if you come across this with the same issue.